# Visual Studio 2013: Resume debugger while ignoring any breakpoints on remainder of the current debug session

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I often find myself in a situation where I wish to break on several breakpoints in a run, but only for a while until I have seen enough on on those breakpoints and would like the Visual Studio to stop breaking on the breakpoints for the remainder of the current debug session.

I certainly do not want to delete all breakpoints because later I may change something in database or the code, and would like to perform a new, similar run to the one described above again.

I do not want to disable all breakpoints, since I want them to be activated again at the next debug run. At the same time I already have breakpoints, both active and disabled, in other parts of the code (which I am not currently interested in for instance) but I do not want to disable them and then try to remember later which I need for debugging a specific area/functionality of the code.

What I want is simply to be able to tell Visual Studio that "from now on as I resume execution, please ignore all breakpoints for the remainder of **this** debugging session. Thank you very much!" 
So for the next debug run, all breakpoints should be hit again as they already were configured before as usual, but I mean at some point when I have seen enough I just want to continue execution without breaking. and without changing the status to "disabled" for all breakpoints - because doing so will make them stay disabled even at the next run, and I do not want to "Enable all" because I already had some breakpoints on my list which were disabled. And I certainly do not want to manually select/deselect breakpoints before every run just because I chose "Disable all" during a run.

Is this possible to and, in that case, how to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: A downvote...okay what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using VS2017 but hopefully the options are similar in VS2013:

Go to the Debug menu, then Windows > Breakpoints to open the Breakpoints window.

[image]

From here, the blue curvy arrows in the toolbar allow you to Export and Import breakpoints into an XML file.

So you could export all of your breakpoints, then delete them all. Later you can re-import them instead of having to set them all up again manually.

Comment: That is a nice workaround!
Not quite the way I imagined, but sure it works and remembers the enabled/disabled state of the breakpoints. I'm a bit hesitant to mark it as The Answer to the problem since it is still a workaround that requires exporting/importing (an remembering to do so when adding a new breakpoint or deleting one) but this is clearly an improvement to the situation I am in right now. So, I give it a Vote Up!

Comment: @10100111001, how about setting up the Conditional breakpoints in Visual Studio: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/05/03/set-a-simple-breakpoint-condition/, so you don't have to disable or remove the breakpoint, and just change the condition manually.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Thanks for the suggestion! However, since I have 5-7 breakpoints that are currently hit multiple times, I would have to change the condition for 5-7 breakpoints manually every run when I have decided that I've seen enough form the data on the breakpoint rows and just want to let it continue application execution without breaking. Also I am having trouble setting up conditions that use the _T() macro in c++. VS complains about "CXX0017: Error: Symbol _T not found" :/

Comment: @10100111001, If so, no good solution for it, Johnny's suggestion would be the best workaround for you. Or you could submit this feature request: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio. The Visual Studio product team is listening to user voice there.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Yes, Johnny's way of doing it would work as a workaround until a proper feature for this gets implemented. Thanks for the link, I shall post a request there!

Comment: @10100111001, You are welcome, if you submit it, you could share it here, so other community members who have the same feature could help you vote it.